# ASP.Net - Base64 convert HTML Turkish character problem

Tags: asp.net

TURKISH_History_Html row data type varbinary. It saves the html code to the row in byte-64 data type as in the photo below. But Turkish characters are not displayed. Turkish characters ?? Displayed as. How can I show Turkish characters?

```
string theString2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(degerler.TURKISH_History_Html);

                    string base64Encoded2 = (theString2);
                    string base64Decoded2;
                    byte[] data2 = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64Encoded2);

                    base64Decoded2 = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data2);
```

[image: database row]
[image: turkish character problem]

Comment: Replace the `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` with `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`, and replace the `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString` with (I assume) `Encoding.UTF8.GetString`, although only you know in which encoding you previously saved that base64.

Comment: ASCII refers to the 7-bit US-ASCII codepage, which contains *no* accented characters. Use `UTF8` instead, eg `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data2)`.

Comment: `TURKISH_History_Html row data type varbinary` why? All databases support Unicode one way or another. If you use SQL Server, you can use `nvarchar` since the 1990s. .NET and Windows strings are UTF16, which means you can store them directly to `nvarchar` without any conversion. SQL Server 2019 added support for UTF8 as a collation for `varchar` fields, in case you care about the storage taken by UTF16. Even without it though, all supported versions and editions support table compression